# How to get imaginary and real part of complex expression symbolically in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I am trying to get the imaginary and real part of following complex expression.

```
syms a b
F = imag((cos(a)-j*sin(a))/(1+j*a*b-cos(a)+j*sin(a)))
simplify(F)
```

The output is same with or without simplify. 
Is there any way to express this expression in standard complex number format (x+jy)?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is assumed about `a` and `b` by default, meaning that they may be complex. Because of this, MATLAB can't determine a closed form expression for the imaginary component. If you know that `a` and `b` are real numbers then you can impose this assumption as follows.

```
syms a b real
F = imag((cos(a)-j*sin(a))/(1+j*a*b-cos(a)+j*sin(a)))
```

Alternatively, you can change the assumptions for a symbolic object after declaration using the [`assume`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/assume.html) function.